# Prove that if for all $a \in A$, $[a]_R⊆[a]_E$ OR $[a]_E⊆[a]_R$ then $R∪E$ is an equivalence relation on set $A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Someone can help me here? Let $R$ and $E$ be equivalence relations on set $A$.  Prove that if for all $a\in A$, $[a]_R⊆[a]_E$ OR $[a]_E⊆[a]_R$ then $R∪E$ is an equivalence relation on set $A$. ( $[a]_E$ and $[a]_R$ are equivalence classes for $E$ and $R$ respectively). Thank you.

Comment: You know what is an equivalence relation, right? You know what properties defined the relation to be an equivalence, right? What properties have you tried to prove? Where did you got stuck?

Answer (score 0):

for all $a \in A, [a]_R⊆[a]_E$ OR $[a]_E⊆[a]_R$
parses as
(for all $a \in A, [a]_R⊆[a]_E$) OR $[a]_E⊆[a]_R$

Do you mean
all $a \in A, ([a]_R⊆[a]_E$ OR $[a]_E⊆[a]_R)$
or
for all $a \in A, [a]_R⊆[a]_E$ OR for all $a \in A[a]_E⊆[a]_R$
which parses as
(for all $a \in A,$ $[a]_R⊆[a]_E$) OR (for all $a \in A,   [a]_E⊆[a]_R$)?

Reflectivity and symmetry of P = R $\cup$ E are direct.
Assume xPy and yPz.
xPz is direct unless (xRy and yEz) or (xRy and yEz).
For the first one
if [y]$_R$ subset [y]$_E$, then x in [y]$_E$, xEz, xPz
if [y]$_E$ subset [y]$_R$, then z in [y]$_R$, xRz, xPz.